# Beginner question about modifying class function call with passed variable

Tags: c++, class, oop, parameter-passing

Need help modifying code.  I am new to classes.

Original code calls a class function and passes in a value derived from calling another class function and then adding 1 to it.  I want to simply pass in a variable value.

I figured out how to cheat by multiplying the returned value by 0 and then adding to that the value I am trying to pass in.  This works but I want to do it right by only passing in the desired value:

Modified code:

```
// sets the temp to a specific value 
void SmartBbq::setProbeAlarm(int probeIndex, float alarmTemp) {
   _smartProbes[probeIndex]->setAlarmTemp(_smartProbes[probeIndex]->getAlarmTemp() * 0 + alarmTemp);
}
```

Original code:

```
// increases temp by 1 degree
void SmartBbq::up() {
    _smartProbes[_active]->setAlarmTemp(_smartProbes[_active]->getAlarmTemp() + 1);
}
```

If this is not enough information I can include the class definitions.  I realize the class definitions may need to be modified as well to accept the incoming argument.  I have made changes there that might be correct but I can't figure out how to properly call the class function with argument.

Adding to my confusion is that it appears one class function calls another adding layers to the complexity.

Comment: Is it `smartProbes[probeIndex]->setAlarmTemp(alarmTemp);` what do you want?

Comment: I see '_smartProbes' and 'smartProbes' both being used. Are both of them valid identifiers?

Comment: @ user888379 Sorry, that is a typo.  It should be '_smartProbes'.  The underscore is missing.  I've fixed my original post.

Comment: @Amadeus I've tried:     _smartProbes[probeIndex]->setAlarmTemp(_smartProbes[probeIndex],alarmTemp); As the probe number also needs to be passed.  But this gives error: no matching function for call to 'SmartProbe::setAlarmTemp(SmartProbe*&, float&)'

Comment: @Pitchlynn for what I got from the minimal code that you have posted, your function signature is: `SmartProbe::setAlarmTemp(float)`. So `_smartProbes[probeIndex]->setAlarmTemp(alarmTemp);` should, at least, compile. BTW, the probe number is being used in the array of `_smartProbes`

Comment: @Amadeus Thanks!  This does compile and is working now.  It is also helpful to know why the probe index did not need to be passed to setAlarmTemp.  This is my first post so I don't seem to have voting or accept privileges.

Comment: @Pitchlynn There is no posted answers to your question, so you can not upvoting or accept. But Im glad that it is working now